# How to create a class extension of a struct?

Tags: ios, glkit

I am dealing with a lot of `GLKmatrix4` elements. These elements are structs declared on `GLKit`.

At one point I want to get the string representation of these elements in row-column order.

If these elements were objects I would create a class extension like this:

```
-(NSString *)getString {

  NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString string];

  [string appendString:[self formatString:self.m00]];
  [string appendString:[self formatString:self.m01]];
  [string appendString:[self formatString:self.m02]];
  [string appendString:[self formatString:self.m03]];
  [string appendString:[self formatString:self.m10]];
  [string appendString:[self formatString:self.m11]];
  [string appendString:[self formatString:self.m12]];
  [string appendString:[self formatString:self.m13]];
  [string appendString:[self formatString:self.m20]];
  [string appendString:[self formatString:self.m21]];
  [string appendString:[self formatString:self.m22]];
  [string appendString:[self formatString:self.m23]];
  [string appendString:[self formatString:self.m30]];
  [string appendString:[self formatString:self.m31]];
  [string appendString:[self formatString:self.m32]];
  [string appendString:[self formatString:self.m33]];
  [string appendString:@"\n"];

  return self;
}

- (NSString *)formatString:(float)value {
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f ", value];
}
```

but `GLKMatrix4` is a struct. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as extenstions or categories for structs. They are plain old C structs. If you look at what apple does, usually it uses C functions to work with their structs. For instance, `CGPointFromString` or `CGRectMake`. You could use the same approach or you could encapsulate all these functions in a class.

Comment: I was suspecting that. Just needed confirmation. THANKS:

Comment: ..and Apple came up with Extension for struct in swift !